# SELECT Statement - Syntax error in query expression ' '

Tags: c#, select, interop, oledb, import-from-excel

Trying to `SELECT` a row in my excel file. I'm using it as a database. I'm pretty sure the problem is either in my query or in my excel file.

`SELECT * FROM [tableName$] where _columnNum1 = 'testData123'"`

I've tried doing this code for a while

`SELECT * FROM [tableName$]`

and it worked. So every time I add a `WHERE` clause, it causes the error. What seems to be the problem here?

The error says `Syntax error in query expression '_columnNum1 = 'testData123''`

UPDATE: I forgot to add this, I've already googled this thing for some time now, and the error is about data types. But since I'm using excel as a database, I can't really manipulate data types around them. Or can I? Anyway maybe the error is about data types.

Comment: I haven't had to query from excel in awhile but shoudn't it be [_columnNum1] ?

Comment: Yes, it should be with square brackets. I didn't need them when I was inserting data so I didn't have any reason adding them here. Still, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of searching, finally got the answer. I simply added brackets on the column name. I didn't need them when I was inserting data in my excel file.

I have the string sql of

`SELECT * FROM [tableName$] where _columnNum1 = 'testData123'"`

when it should be

`SELECT * FROM [tableName$] where [_columnNum1] = 'testData123'"`

I got the answer here:

SOURCE: [OLE CALL to Excel with WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805925/ole-call-to-excel-with-where-clause)

Another note, for people who has trouble inserting data in their excel where the data does not go to the first row, the source might be the answer, too.