# C# MVC Datatable just showing 1000 rows even the data is fewer

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, model-view-controller, datatable

Hello I have problem when i try to load excel rows to datatable JS.
heres's my code

controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Aplikasi(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
        string filePath = string.Empty;
        string extension = string.Empty;
        DataTable dtSheet = new DataTable();
        DataSet ExcelData = new DataSet();
        if (postedFile != null)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            filePath = path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
            extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
            postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

        }
        if (postedFile ==null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        string connectionString = string.Empty;

        //milih constring tergantung file
        switch (extension)
        {
            case ".xls": //<= 2003 version
                connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;
            case ".xlsx": //>= 2007 version
                connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;
        }

        //oledb koneksi
        connectionString = string.Format(connectionString, filePath);
        using (OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            
            using (OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter odaExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

                    //ambil nama sheet #1
                    connExcel.Open();
                    DataTable dtExcelSchema;
                    dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    string sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                    connExcel.Close();

                    //ambill data dari sheet #1
                    connExcel.Open();
                    cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";
                    odaExcel.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
                    //dapetin data dimasukin ke dtSheet
                    odaExcel.Fill(dtSheet);
                    connExcel.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        ExcelData.Tables.Add(dtSheet);
        return View(ExcelData);
    }
```

View Page (actually i just skip some line, just showing that relate with this case)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "App", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
<div class="input-group">
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input type="file" name="postedFile" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <span> <input type="submit" name="Import" /></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
@if (Model != null)
    {
        <table id="tablePenerima" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Pilih</th>
                    @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Tables[0].Columns)
                    {

                        <th align="center">@col.ColumnName</th>
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Tables[0].Columns)
                        {

                            <td align="center">@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
                        }

                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
```

The JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tablePenerima').DataTable({
            'columnDefs': [
                {
                    'targets': 0,
                    'checkboxes': {
                        'selectRow': true
                    }
                }
            ],
            'select': {
                'style': 'multi'
            },

            'order': [[1, 'asc']]
        });

    });
</script>
```

and it just shows 1000 rows even the rows from excel just 4 rows. And when i check all, it will check the all rows, not the 4 existing datas.

Here's the screenshot :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVhLv.png)

How can i get rid of this problem? thank you

Comment: Excel spreadsheets have 1000s of rows that are empty. You should filter out empty data before returning it to your view.

Comment: yes, how to do that in controller or somthing. i dunno how to implement

Comment: You need to add a where clause to your select * statement. Check this link out. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805925/ole-call-to-excel-with-where-clause&ved=2ahUKEwjBl9_quo_0AhUbbc0KHSb-AGYQFnoECAUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2OlIcX4jl3a4IH_DbGAmbT

Answer (score 0):

Add a where clause to your select statement

```
cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "] WHERE [ColumnName] <>' ' ";
```

Comment: oh man, you save my life. i use
"SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "] WHERE NAMA IS NOT NULL";
Because i just wanna read if the NAMA collumn is not empty.
Thanks for the solution .

Comment: No problem. Vote it up if it worked for you.